# 27 days after domain transfer name servers not propogated

Tags: nameserver, domain-name-system

We recently bought the domain: *****.com

7 days after accepting the transfer the domain finally transferred to our registrar and we immediately changed the name servers from `ns*.netregistry.net` to `amy.ns.cloudflare.com` and `cody.ns.cloudflare.com`

20 days after changing the name servers, the majority of tests show that both old and new nameservers are still being reported:

http://intodns.com/*****

http://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/*****

We are now ready to launch the new site but this issue is plagueing us as a high proportion of the traffic is still receiving the old nameserves and so hitting the old server.

You can tell if you have hit the old or new server as the old server has the value "A" for the meta tag "Location" and the new server has "U". (The old server just has an iframe too!)

I have never had this problem before - who is causing this and how should we go about reaching a resolution?

Thanks

---

**Update**

Our registrar, 123-reg, accepted this was their fault and someone on their end was able to fix it.

To reiterate what was said in responses the issue was solely due to them.

Comment: Who is the new registrar?

Comment: Please accept an Answer (green checkmark next to the Answer) if it helped you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whois lists your name servers as amy.ns.cloudflare.com and cody.ns.cloudflare.com, but the parent servers (the gTLD servers) list ns1.netregistry.net, ns2.netregistry.net and ns3.netregistry.net as well as amy.ns.cloudflare.com and cody.ns.cloudflare.com as the name servers for your domain.

You need to fix this at your domain registrar as they're the party that is responsible for updating the parent servers. Show them this trace:

> **Tracing DNS delegation for "****.com"**
>
> **Loading root server list**
>
> a.root-servers.net (198.41.0.4)
>
> b.root-servers.net (192.228.79.201)
>
> c.root-servers.net (192.33.4.12)
>
> d.root-servers.net (128.8.10.90)
>
> e.root-servers.net (192.203.230.10)
>
> f.root-servers.net (192.5.5.241)
>
> g.root-servers.net (192.112.36.4)
>
> h.root-servers.net (128.63.2.53)
>
> i.root-servers.net (192.36.148.17)
>
> j.root-servers.net (192.58.128.30)
>
> k.root-servers.net (193.0.14.129)
>
> l.root-servers.net (199.7.83.42)
>
> m.root-servers.net (202.12.27.33)
>
> **Sending request to "e.root-servers.net" (192.203.230.10)**
>
> **Received referral response - DNS servers for "com"**
>
> a.gtld-servers.net (192.5.6.30)
>
> b.gtld-servers.net (192.33.14.30)
>
> c.gtld-servers.net (192.26.92.30)
>
> d.gtld-servers.net (192.31.80.30)
>
> e.gtld-servers.net (192.12.94.30)
>
> f.gtld-servers.net (192.35.51.30)
>
> g.gtld-servers.net (192.42.93.30)
>
> h.gtld-servers.net (192.54.112.30)
>
> i.gtld-servers.net (192.43.172.30)
>
> j.gtld-servers.net (192.48.79.30)
>
> k.gtld-servers.net (192.52.178.30)
>
> l.gtld-servers.net (192.41.162.30)
>
> m.gtld-servers.net (192.55.83.30)
>
> **Sending request to "a.gtld-servers.net" (192.5.6.30)**
>
> **Received referral response - DNS servers for "****.com"**
>
> ns3.netregistry.net (203.55.142.11)
>
> ns1.netregistry.net (203.55.143.10)
>
> ns2.netregistry.net (203.55.143.100)
>
> amy.ns.cloudflare.com (173.245.58.101)
>
> cody.ns.cloudflare.com (173.245.59.107)

Comment: +1 The registrar is still giving invalid information to the TLD name servers.

Answer (score 4):

Your whois record shows only the two (correct) nameservers:

```
Nameserver:             amy.ns.cloudflare.com
Nameserver:             cody.ns.cloudflare.com
```

So I speculate that something went wrong with the domain transfer, and you need to contact [your registrar](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/) to have it fixed.

Comment: I have spoke to them a few times over the last couple of weeks - they attribute it to the name servers being cached in some locations. Do you think there is something they could/should do?

Comment: Besides hire someone competent? They do look kind of dodgy...